# Rename object names in methods

Tags: java, object, arraylist, naming

I've got a piece of code

```
list.add(new Person())
```

Since the Person object is missing it's naming part

```
Person p = new Person()
```

What kind of name does this person object get assigned to?

Is it important to know the name of the object?
How would I go about accessing this object's methods if it is added to the ArrayList without a name?

edit: name == reference. I know objects don't have names

Comment: You should try and read a book about how OO programming actually works, since this question is the definition of a too broad of a question.

Comment: Objects don't have names, variables do. You need to read a basic tutorial and fast.

Comment: Let me say, answer depends on your implementation of `Person` class, if you have over there class field `name` and overriden default constructor, where are you setting some name, than it will take this name, otherwise this person will dont have any name set. Notice "p" is variable name, name of instance, not name of "object", for access, take a look in [`get` method of arraylist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` is not "the name of the object". `p` is a variable that happens to hold a reference to the `Person` object. Objects don't have names.

If you skip declaring the `p` variable and add the `Person` object directly to the `ArrayList`, the `ArrayList` still holds a reference to that object, so it doesn't matter whether you use `list.add(new Person())` or `list.add(p)`.

Either way you can retrieve the reference to the `Person` with `list.get(index)`, and then execute any methods you wish.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it needed to have an original reference before being added to an arraylist

Answer (score 2):

I think, that the name of the Person-Object doens't matter.
You can simply access it with `list.get(int number)`.
This will give you the refernce to the element at the position.

Hope I understood your question correctly and this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

The name is only used by developers for reference, it's not actually needed at runtime.
To access your object you'd use:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>(); // Create the list
list.add(new Person()); // Add the person to the list

list.get(0); // Returns the person you added
```

If you want to get specific people from your list I'd suggestion using a HashMap and store their names as the keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confusing the creation of an object with assigning a reference to that object. In you example p is a reference to the object Person that you have created. You have not named that object p, but have a reference called p to the object person.

To create a reference to the person object from list.add(new Person()) you simply do a

```
Person p = list.get(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object from its index in the List.

Comment: This hardly is an appropriate answer to these broad questions

Answer (score 0):

An object lives in JVM memory heap, and doesn't have such a thing as a name. It can be referenced by variables that can be lists or single elements. In the case of the list you can reference the object by accessing the list element by its index.